# Refresh de página conflitando entre laravel e vuejs

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5, vue-router

Estou estudando a integração entre laravel e vuejs, contudo, quando configuro as rotas pelo vue-router, ao fazer um refresh na página, o laravel não encontra a página ou então, preciso voltar no index da aplicação para funcionar tudo de novo. Sendo mais específico, vamos supor que eu tenho uma rota que retorna um json com alguns nomes, na página específica, será populada uma lista com o vuejs, só que ao dar um refresh na página, o laravel não identifica que o routing do vuejs e envia apenas o json cru, ao invés de retornar o json para o vuejs e a partir daí popular a página. Eu preciso voltar ao index da aplicação, clicar novamente no link da página que eu quero ir e aí sim pegar os dados através do vue. Se eu der um refresh na página acontece tudo novamente, em resumo, toda a vez que a página é atualizada com f5, o laravel não identifica o routing do vuejs. Se a página não retorna dados, o laravel exibe a típica página de não encontrado, se há retorno de dados, é mostrado os dados cru, direto na página, sem passar pelo vuejs. Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Poderia postar partes de seu código do laravel e vuejs? Posso tentar fazer um exemplo de comunicação entre o vue com o vue-resource e o laravel, é algo que te ajudaria? Pois o problema em si não sei te dizer como resolver sem ao menos ver o código.

Comment: guastallaigor, é algo a ver com o mode: history do vuejs. Retirei isso da aplicação e agora tudo funciona corretamente. Porém, não gostaria de ter na url este `#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felipe, passei por esse mesmo problema agora pouco e tratei da seguinte forma:

Deixei a rota web(routes/web.php) da seguinte forma:

```
Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

Assim todas as rotas vão jogar para a minha view que chama o vue, e as chamadas para a api foram todas para a rota de api(routes/api.php), no vue as chamadas para o laravel serão todas no /api

Estou iniciando com o VueJs essa semana então pode ser errado trabalhar dessa forma, mas para mim pareceu fazer sentido essa forma, pois assim já estou deixando a API pronta para ser consumida pelo front, e qualquer chamada web o Laravel simplesmente passa a responsabilidade de interpretar a rota para o Vue.

Caso eu esteja errado nesse pensamento, por favor alguém me corrija.